# jQuery - Run a function when user has scrolled up 100px from current location

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am trying to run a function once the user has scrolled up 100px and another function when they scroll down (any number of pixels) from there current location. So if the user scrolls half way down a page and then starts to scroll up i need a function to run once they have scrolled up 100px from the current stored scrollTop value.

If the user was 700px down the page and they started to scroll up I need a function to run when they hit 600px. This should be dynamic from where ever the user is down the page.

As a starting point i have:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (st > lastScrollTop){
        // Scrolling down
    } else {
        // Scrolling up
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Also, I'd suggest you have a read of John Resig's blog post about [attaching handlers to the window scroll event](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/)

Comment: @billyonecan I am trying to run a function when the user scrolls up 100px from where ever they are on the page. So if they are 700px down and then scroll up and function will run when they hit 600px. Question edited.

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle(http:/jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gWD66/1/)

Try this link. May be its very helpful for you

use this Code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var position = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > position) {
      moveCarDownward(scroll);  // $('#status').html('going down!');
    } else {
       moveCarUpward(scroll);  //$('#status').html('going up!');
    }
    position = scroll;
});
```

one another link which one in javascript [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Aletheios/hWmNj/)

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to run a function when the user starts scrolling up, not reaching the bottom